# What is wrong with this if condition in powershell?

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, logic, powershell-2.0

i am trying to find the service running, also checking the right version and above is there in my machine if yes , then i need to return 1 else zero

I need to check

> Condition 1 : $servicestatus = true

OR

```
Condition 2 : Where Status -ne "Running" = true
```

AND

> Condition 3 :  Get-ItemProperty
> HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* |
> Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
> Where-Object {$*.DisplayName -like "Crow*" -and $*.DisplayVersion -gt
> 6.28} command should have atleast 1 record

Then exit 1

> if no record in condition 3 then exit 0

**Issue**

But when

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Where-Object {$*.DisplayName -like "Crow*" -and $*.DisplayVersion -gt 6.28} **result having a record or not, then entire code is resulting 1**

But I am ***expecting zero*** when no records have resulted in a third condition.

Please help: here is the full code i written

```
$servicestatus = get-service 'something'
If (@($servicestatus | Where Status -ne "Running" | Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Crow*" -and $_.DisplayVersion -gt 6.28}).Count -gt 0)
    {
        echo "1"
       Exit 1
       
    }
Else
    {
        echo "1"
       Exit 0
    }
```

I modified code to add an and condition but still no luck

```
$servicestatus = get-service 'something'
If (@(($servicestatus | Where Status -ne "Running" ) -and (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate  | Where {($_.DisplayName -like "Crow*") -and ($_.DisplayVersion -gt 6.28)})).Count -gt 0)
    {
        echo "1"
       Exit 1
       
    }
Else
    {
        echo "1"
       Exit 0
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify: `(C1 or C2) and C3` or `C1 or (C2 and C3)`

Comment: (C1 or C2) and C3

Comment: Sorry , i echo 1 in both places sorry for trouble :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sometime weird but you may want to set every condition separated by `-and`, `-or` and so on in brackets, like this:

```
| Where {($_.DisplayName -like "Crow*") -and ($_.DisplayVersion -gt 6.28)}
```

As far as I know the reason is that powershell thinks that `-and` is a parameter of a previous expression (string in this example).

#### To edited code:

Try this instead:

```
if(($servicestatus.Status -ne "Running") -and ((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Where-Object {($_.DisplayName -like "Crow*") -and ($_.DisplayVersion -gt 6.28)}).Count -gt 0))
```

Comment: If (@($servicestatus | Where Status -ne "Running" | Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate  | Where {($_.DisplayName -like "Crow*") -and ($_.DisplayVersion -gt 6.28)}).Count -gt 0)

Comment: I think there's also an error in your interpretation of  this `$servicestatus | Where Status -ne "Running" | Get-ItemProperty`. You want to check if there's something in HKLM if service is not running, am I correct?

Comment: loosk like issue is becouse i put or instead of and in third conidition

Comment: I tried this If (@(($servicestatus | Where Status -ne "Running" ) -and (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate  | Where {($_.DisplayName -like "Crow*") -and ($_.DisplayVersion -gt 6.28)})).Count -gt 0)
but still not working

Comment: (C1 or C2) and C3

Comment: please add your code and what you've tried in question. It's unreadable in comments

Comment: Done, i am trying to find the service running, also checking the right version and above is there in my machine if yes , then i need to return 1 else zero

Comment: Dude ...i echo 1 in both placess , sorry for trouble